# Single JavaScript function on individual WordPress Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have read through a few articles on how to add JavaScript to WordPress pages though it seems overly complex for what I need. I have this small script (see below) and I want it to work on just 1 page. I thought adding it within `<script>` tags after the main content would do the trick but I get the following error in the Console:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Even though the script works fine in the console, it doesn't work.

For this script do I have to use the complex methods or is there a simpler one?

```js
$('#tSubmit').on('click', function() {
    var amt = +$('#tCount').val(),
        tier = $('#tType').val(),
        h = +$('#tH').val() > 0 ? +$('#tH').val() : 0,
        m = +$('#tM').val() > 0 ? +$('#tM').val() : 0,
        s = +$('#tS').val() > 0 ? +$('#tS').val() : 0,
        time = ((h*60+m)*60+s)/amt;
    alert('Individual time for Tier ' + tier + ' troops: ' + time.toFixed(2) + ' seconds');
});
```

Comment: Do you have jQuery included on your page?

Comment: Are you sure your code is executed after your form is displayed on the page?

Comment: wordpress theme likely using noConflict, try replacing `$` with `jQuery`

Comment: Yes, jQuery is included in the theme.
The script doesn't get executed until `#tSubmit` is clicked.

Comment: You should mark this answered even if the answer wasn't the first one, it is more complete. Also not marking it answered keeps the Q in the unanswered state, which it isn't.

Comment: @AndrewHoffman You can't mark it as an answer straight away. I have now though

Comment: @Spedwards sorry, disregard. :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In WordPress jQuery is loaded using the [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) function, which means that the `$` variable is aliased to `jQuery` so as to not conflict with other Javascript libraries.

You can include your javascript in your page template, or even within the post content (if you are using the text editor, not visual), as long as you replace `$` with `jQuery`.

```
jQuery('#tSubmit').on('click', function() {
    var amt = +jQuery('#tCount').val(),
        tier = jQuery('#tType').val(),
        h = +jQuery('#tH').val() > 0 ? +jQuery('#tH').val() : 0,
        m = +jQuery('#tM').val() > 0 ? +jQuery('#tM').val() : 0,
        s = +jQuery('#tS').val() > 0 ? +jQuery('#tS').val() : 0,
        time = ((h*60+m)*60+s)/amt;
    alert('Individual time for Tier ' + tier + ' troops: ' + time.toFixed(2) + ' seconds');
});
```

If you don't want to change the code, you can pass the `jQuery` variable into a function that takes `$` as an argument, and use your code as is.

```
(function($){
    // your code goes here and jQuery is known as $
    // $(document).on()... or whatever
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to create a separated js file for this functionality (and also execute it on jQuery(document).ready()) and then, refer to it from your page with wp_enqueue_script('scrip name', 'script url', array('jQuery')). That will make your script load after jQuery was loaded.